# WinForms - Error creating window handle on UseSystemPasswordChar

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I am working on a project involving a library management system, and I use a custom made class called "PlaceholderTextBox" to act as a TextBox with a Placeholder Text:

```
internal class PlaceholderTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool isPlaceHolder = true;
    private string _PlaceholderText;
    private bool isPassword;

    public string PlacehoderText
    {
        get { return _PlaceholderText; }
        set { _PlaceholderText = value; setPlaceholder(); }
    }

    public bool IsPassword
    {
        get { return isPassword; }
        set { isPassword = value; }
    }

    private void setPlaceholder()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            this.Text = PlacehoderText;
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            isPlaceHolder = true;
            if (isPassword) this.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        }
    }

    private void removePlaceHolder()
    {
        if (isPlaceHolder)
        {
            if (isPassword) this.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            this.Text = "";
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            isPlaceHolder = false;
        }
    }

    public PlaceholderTextBox()
    {
        GotFocus += removePlaceHolder;
        LostFocus += setPlaceholder;
    }

    private void setPlaceholder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setPlaceholder();
    }

    private void removePlaceHolder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removePlaceHolder();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this class is an extended version of TextBox class, which can handle Placeholder Text, as well as password bulleting in case I needed.

The problem arise on void setPlaceholder() function, on line "if (isPassword) this.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;" which throws me a "Win32Exception" which states "Error creating window handle" each time I try to press the textbox, and the placeholder text should be replaced with actual password text which should be bulleted.

Any ideas on why the program throws me this exception, and ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Setting the UseSystemPasswordChar forces the winforms engine to recreate your textbox. Probably this exception is caused by this behavior

Comment: That is a "difficult" property, it requires Winforms to recreate the control.  Doing this in a focus event is very dangerous, destroying the control forces the focus to be moved.  So this happens over and over again, the OS pulls the plug after it has recreated the control ~10,000 times.  The universal work around for code in an event handler that has too many side-effects is to delay that code.  Elegantly done with this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { code here }));

Comment: Still gives me an error: Additional information: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'System.Windows.Forms!System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+WndProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

This is how I entered the code: 

this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { if (isPassword) { this.UseSystemPasswordChar = true; } }));

Comment: You must also use the Enter and Leave events, Get/LostFocus are too dangerous.  And there is a possible initialization problem, only make the assignment when necessary so this is only ever done after the control is created and BeginInvoke can work.  If you still have trouble, consider that this just is never useful code, you always want to have it set to *true*.

Comment: Yes, the replacement of GetFocus/ LostFocus with Enter and Leave solved the problem. I'll keep that in mind next time! Thank you very much!